# is it possible to to have a fixed width on geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with bunch of different data frames which could have multiple variables or a singel variable:

my data frame looks like this:
 x

```
Team         Grade
Football      10
```

When I do this, bar size is huge. I would like to have a fix size so that it looks good when there is one or 2 rows of data:

```
ggplot(x, aes(Team, Grade, group=Team)) + geom_bar(aes(fill=Team))
```

Answer (score 4):

If your data look like this:

```
df <- data.frame(Team=gl(4, 1), Grade=sample(1:4))
```

You can specify the width of the bar as follows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Team, y=Grade, fill=Team)) + geom_bar(width=0.2)
```

Which gives this plot:

[image]

A similar data set, but with only one Team, is given by:

```
ggplot(subset(df, Team==1), aes(x=Team, y=Grade, fill=Team)) + geom_bar(width=0.2)
```

[image]

Which looks OK, I think.

If you are more concerned about the situation where you only have one Team (or a few), and the bars all go to the top of the plot, you can set y limits:

```
+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0, 4))
```

[image]

Comment: It's not clear whether he's referring to the height or the width of the bar. Perhaps adding information on how to set limits, or breaks to the scale would be helpful as well.